# OSX applescript - check if the application in focus is not finder, otherwise do not execute command

Tags: applescript

I am a bit rusty with applescript; trying to find out if the current application in focus is finder, and if it is, the program shall bail. Otherwise, it should perform a command.

The problem is that I can't find a way to check if the current app in focus is finder. Did search online and there are examples that show how to bring an app in focus, but I just want to retrieve the name of the app that has focus; and do a check to see if the script should bail out or continue. Something like this; although I have no command to check the application in focus.

```
tell application "System Events"
    # check if finder is the process on focus
    if "Finder" is in focus then
        display dialog ("Finder is in front")
    else
        display dialog ("Finder is not in front")
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every application regardless whether it has an AppleScript dictionary or not has a `frontmost` property.

So you can simply write (`System Events` is not needed)

```
if frontmost of application "Finder" then
    display dialog ("Finder is in front")
else
    display dialog ("Finder is not in front")
end if
```

Comment: Does anyone know what the equivalent of this would be in Javascript for OSX Automation ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to check and see if **Finder** is frontmost:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "System Events" to set frontmostVisibleApp to ¬
    (name of every process whose frontmost is true and visible is true) as string

if frontmostVisibleApp is "Finder" then return
```

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax you want:

```
tell application "System Events"
    # check if finder is the process on focus
    if frontmost of process "Finder" is true then
        display dialog ("Finder is in front")
    else
        display dialog ("Finder is not in front")
    end if
end tell
```

This will throw an error if the Finder isn't running, as I'm sure you know. That seems like an unlikely case, but if it's something you're worried about you can turn the code around:

```
tell application "System Events"
    # check if finder is the process on focus
    set frontProcessName to name of first process whose frontmost is true
    if frontProcessName is "Finder" then
        display dialog ("Finder is in front")
    else
        display dialog ("Finder is not in front")
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Why invoke _System Events_ to do this ?

Comment: Habit, I suppose.