# AppleScript behaving differently when run in Java code

Tags: java, applescript

I wrote some AppleScript that opens and application and creates a record. The script behaves as expected when run in Script editor. When running this script from my Java code, the script doesn't function the same. The script will activate the application but not put it into focus.

Applescript:

```
   tell application "Daylite" to activate

tell application "System Events" to set frontmostVisibleApp to "Daylite"

tell application "System Events"
    
    keystroke "o" using {shift down, command down}
    delay 0.1
    key code 49
    key code 123
    repeat 16 times
        key code 51
    end repeat
    delay 0.1
    set the clipboard to "Quote-230316-1"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
    delay 0.5
    key code 76
    repeat 13 times
        key code 48
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    delay 0.5
    key code 76
    delay 0.1
    set the clipboard to "Joe Smith"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
    delay 0.1
    key code 76
    delay 0.1
    click button "Save" of window "New Opportunity" of application process "Daylite" of application "System Events"
    
end tell
```

Java code:

```
    public void CreateDayliteOpportunity()
   {
     
      
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      String applescriptCommand =  "tell application \"Daylite\" activate\n" +
                                   "delay 2\n"+
                                   "run script\n"+
                                   "tell application \"System Events\" to set frontmostVisibleApp to \"Daylite\""+
                                   "delay 0.1\n"+
                                   "tell application \"System Events\"\n" +
                                   "keystroke \"o\" using {shift down, command down}\n"+
                                   "delay 0.1\n"+
                                    "key code 49\n"+
                                    "key code 123\n"+
                                    "repeat 16 times\n"+
                                    "key code 51\n"+
                                    "end repeat\n"+
                                    "delay 0.1\n"+
                                    "set the clipboard to \"" + OpportunityName + "\"\n"+
                                    "delay 0.1\n"+
                                    "keystroke \"v\" using {command down}\n"+
                                    "delay 0.5\n"+
                                    "key code 76\n"+
                                    "repeat 13 times\n"+
                                    "key code 48\n"+
                                    "delay 0.2\n"+
                                    "end repeat\n"+
                                    "delay 0.5\n"+
                                    "key code 76\n"+
                                    "delay 0.1\n"+
                                    "set the clipboard to \"" + ContactName + "\"\n"+
                                    "delay 0.1\n"+
                                    "keystroke \"v\" using {command down}\n"+
                                    "delay 0.1\n"+
                                    "key code 76\n"+
                                    "delay 0.1\n"+
                                    "click button \"Save\" of window \"New Opportunity\" of application process \"Daylite\" of application \"System Events\"\n"+
                                   "end tell";

      String[] args = { "osascript", "-e", applescriptCommand };
      try
      {
      Process process = runtime.exec(args);
      }
      catch(IOException xyz)
      {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR! " + xyz.getMessage());}
   }
```

Comment: If the code in the java code segment is supposed to run literally, then you're missing the word `to` before `activate` in the first line of applescript code. If you're running a command within the tell statement (as opposed to inside a tell block) then you must include 'to'. You have it within the applescript code segment. Typically, excluding 'to' generates a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains a code fragment (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847676/279798)?) that accidentally tries to set the app's focus by checking a variable. `frontmostVisibleApp` is indeed just a variable though and does not perform any action. Your use of `tell application "Daylite" to activate` should be sufficient to give it focus. What further were you looking to cause to happen?

To move forward, I'd suggest just removing that line. Then perhaps lengthen that pause if it is sometimes launching Daylite rather than just giving it focus, e.g. via:

```
tell application "Daylite" to activate
delay 4
```

Or, less clumsily, you could further fail-*safe* by, for example, wrapping the rest in a focus check:

```
if (frontmost of application "Daylite") is true then
    --code
end if
```

Or, my recommendation, add a full wait loop after the `activate` command:

```
repeat until (frontmost of application "Daylite") is true
    delay 1
end repeat

--code
```